Script does not work when run from Startup Programs
It works when run in a terminal, but not when run from Startup Programs.
It starts a terminal window and Alt+F9 minimizes that window.
It doesn't produce any errors.
mate-terminal
sleep 5
xdotool search --class terminal key --window %@ "alt+F9"


Please edit the question and add what it does do, Is there an error and if so what? Where exactly are you placing the script and how do you expect it to be triggered?

try adding .desktop file to $HOME/.config/autostart/

A bell rang somewhere and I now recall this issue with MATE terminal.
The issue is that the first mate-terminal process run on the system acts more or less like a "server" to which all MATE terminal instances connect. One instance is spawned immediately and more may be spawned later.
Because of this, the first mate-terminal process that is run on the system keeps running as its own stand-alone process as long as there are MATE terminal instances connected to it; if this first process happens to be run in a script, it blocks the execution of further commands in the script.
This isn't true for MATE terminal instances spawned when a "server" is running already, as those will connect to the running server and return control to the shell immediately.
Since MATE terminal is the default terminal on Ubuntu MATE, your script worked because you either ran your tests in a MATE terminal instance or there was a MATE terminal instance running on the system already at the time you ran your tests.
But your script won't work if you try and close down every MATE terminal instance running on the system and run the script, say, in xterm.
The solution in this case is to background the mate-terminal process in the shell, in order to prevent it from blocking the execution of further commands in case it happens to become the "server" (which is pretty much every time since the process is run basically as soon as MATE is fully started up; I tested this script on a fresh Ubuntu MATE 24.04 VM and it works for me, unlike your version lacking the & which just spawns the MATE terminal instance without minimizing it):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mate-terminal &
sleep 5
xdotool search --class terminal key --window %@ "alt+F9"


It did not work.

It looks like this is unsolvable when the script is added to the Startup Programs. Is there a way to start the script after the computer boots?

@fixit7 I spun up a Ubuntu MATE 24.04 VM just to test this; the script doesn't work for me if I don't background the mate-terminal process with & (as expected), and it works for me if I background the mate-terminal process using &. So please do some basic sanity check: does the path in Startup Application point to the right script? Have you applied the fix correctly? Does the script have a shebang? Is the script executable?

At the end of the day though, this is the correct answer.  I would use the getactivewindow logic, but either way, I would have to see it to believe it my friend. mate-terminal & has to work.  The startup problem being explained, I believe it could be remedied with a nohup.

@kos You might stick this on there for convenience, but I don't think it will make or break anyone's success either way.

@JayCravens When you add a startup script through GNOME / KDE / MATE, a .desktop file is automatically generated in ~/.config/autostart (adding desktop files to this folder is the Freedesktop-compliant way of setting up startup scripts, so you can expect many desktop environments to follow this convention), so that step is unnecessary when adding startup script through the GUI (actually, putting in another .desktop file would make the script run twice). For example, on my MATE test VM, this is the auto-generated .desktop file: https://pastebin.com/u7NuFZN9

@JayCravens I too think the way the window is targeted could be improved. Again the problem with getactivewindow is the race condition with other startup scripts / the user. But if you want to try and improve on simply adding & (which just solves the issue at hand), I agree that fiddling with xdotool and make it target the window more precisely / with less delay is probably the way to go

@JayCravens nohup will only protect mate-terminal from SIGHUPs. Unless the parent shell is SIGHUPped for some reason (or the nohup process itself is SIGHUPped), I don't think the process could be SIGHUPped due to other reasons. I may be wrong though, I'm kinda rusty on signals and all that jazz

@kos It would launch the terminal in a separate process that doesn’t tie it to the parent shell, so, depending on mate-terminal, it would be a way to try and remedy the startup blocking issue.  Worth a shot, anyhow.

@JayCravens nohup mate-terminal on its own would run in the parent shell, nohup mate-terminal >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown (or nohup mate-terminal &>/dev/null & disown if POSIX-uncompliance doesn't trigger you) would be the idiomatic way to fully detach a process from the shell; I doesn't accomplish much in this case though (besides the resilience to SIGHUP signals)

I put this in /home/andy/.config/autostart/.
Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/andy/bin/minimize_mate_terminal.sh
Hidden=false
Name[en_US]=Minimize Mate terminal
Name=Minimize Mate terminal
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
X-MATE-Autostart-Delay=0

In minimize_mate_terminal.sh
sleep 3

xdotool search --class terminal key --window %@ "alt+F9"

And this in Startup Applications.
mate-teminal
